# Rails simple form undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form-for

I want to create a simple form to make new reviews for a recipe that has been posted in a cookbook. I render the review form on the recipe show page, but it keeps giving me the same error:

*undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass*

When I do not render the partial new review form at **app/views/recipes/show.html.erb**,  but instead I create the file **app/views/reviews/new.html.erb**, only then the form works. I do not understand why the form is not working when I try to render it at show recipe page.

**Here is my code:**

**Simple form for:**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@review, url: recipe_reviews_path(@recipe)) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input :content %>
    <%= f.input :rating %>
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

**Reviews controller:**

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @recipe = recipe.find(params[:recipe_id])
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
  end

  def create
    @recipe = recipe.find(params[:recipe_id])
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.recipe = @recipe
    if @review.save
      redirect_to recipe_path(@recipe)
    else
      render 'recipe/show'
    end
  end

  private

  def review_params
    params.require(:review).permit(:content, :rating)
  end
end
```

**Recipes controller:**

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
  def index
    @recipes = Recipe.all
  end

  def show
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find(@recipe.user_id)
    @full_name = @recipe.user.first_name + " " + @recipe.user.last_name
  end
end
```

**Recipe show page:**

```
<div class="review">
  <%= render 'review/new' %>

  <% @recipe.reviews.each do |review| %>
      <%= review.content %>
      <%= review.rating %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**Routes:**

```
 resources :recipes, only: [:index, :show] do
    resources :reviews, only: [:create]
  end
```

**Models:**

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :ingredients, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, :summary, :course, :kitchen, :photo, :description, presence: true
  validates :summary, length: { maximum: 30 }
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

model review:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe

  validates :content, length: { minimum: 20 }
  validates :rating, presence: true
  validates_numericality_of :rating, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0, :less_than_or_equal_to => 5
  validates :content, presence: true
end
```

Can anyone see the problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Would you mind to post the models and RecipesController, please?

Comment: I believe your problem lies in the fact that **@recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])** is not finding a corresponding recipe and then returning nil. Then, in the view, when you say **@recipe.reviews.each** it complains that you're referencing a model name (Review) from a nil class.

Comment: Besides, in your show view you say **render 'review/new'** but I can't see a new method in your ReviewsController. Do you have an **app/views/review/_new.html.erb** file?

Comment: I do have an app/views/review/_new.html.erb file. I first had a new method  inside the ReviewsController, but that did not make any difference.

Comment: When I comment out the **<%= render 'review/new' %>** inside the **app/views/recipes/show.html.erb**, then everything works fine. Of course the creating a review part is the thing I cannot get to work. The reason why I render the review new form at the **app/views/recipes/show.html.erb** is because I want to use Ajax at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a new instance of Review model in the show action of RecipesController

> @review = Review.new

That's all. It will work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have new method in your RecipesController? since you using @recipe in the simpleform view. You need

```
def new
@recipe = recipe.find(params[:recipe_id])
@review = Review.new(review_params)
end
```

Comment: I edited for the sake of indentation. Good indentation helps a lot when it comes to understanding code.

Comment: I have added the new method now in the RecipesController, but I still get the error. :(

Comment: I think it is complaining about: **<%= simple_form_for(@review, url: recipe_reviews_path(@recipe)) do |f| %>**

Comment: No problem, @PadmanabanGokula. I hope you don't get angry. It is just a matter of keeping the quality of code and I'm sure you understand how important this is.

Comment: @Seifer Can you try this please. <%= simple_form_for([@review, @receipe]) do |f| %>

Comment: @EddeAlmeida I agree :)

Comment: @PadmanabanGokula Don't you mean <%= simple_form_for([@recipe, @review]) do |f| %> ? When I try ([@review, @recipe]) it raises an error about undefined method content. Btw ([@recipe, @review]) doesn't work either, it will give me the same error are stated in the topic title.